# MS Chart Control - How to change X Axis location

Tags: asp.net, charts, mschart

We want to draw spline chart with both –Ve and +Ve values using MS chart control library in .Net 4.0 .The x-axis label, the dark line legends are always shown at the bottom of the chart.We want to move x axis line and legends, to the 0th position on Y axis  .Basically in the middle of the chart (vertically). Has anybody done that ? Anybody knows properties to be set for achieving this.Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: this question and its answer are useful. please consider posting the answer below, and not in the question area.

Comment: I answered the question by cutting-and-pasting the solution presented by the OP into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following property settings solves the issue:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Crossing = 0.00;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Crossing = 0.00;
```